# Spaces Control+Number stops working on Yosemite

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, osx-yosemite, osx-spaces, mission-control

I verified that the shortcuts are enabled (in Keyboard preference), but occasionally <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>, <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd>, etc stop working on my computer. It works again when I reboot. I'm on Yosemite 10.10.3

What's strange is I can still switch spaces via <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>arrow key</kbd>.

Comment: Deleting ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.symbolichotkeys.plist  works to fix this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the exact same problem.

To fix it I renamed that **com.apple.symbolichotkeys.plist** file to **com.apple.symbolichotkeys.plist.backup** (just in case), then ran `killall Dock` and then restarted Dock via Spotlight and now it works fine again.

I have ctrl-1, ctrl-2, etc mapped to spaces. A habit from my Linux days.

Comment: This fixed the exact same issue in May 2019 on my Mac with MacOS 10.13.6. Google+StackExchange is a miracle!